# Regex Manipulation

Tags: android, regex, string

I have a string "Number=12345678; Message=this \n is \n a \n sample \n text;" and I use regex "\{(.*?)}\" to split the string by number and by message but the problem is the "\n" in Message is also being split. How can i remove the "\" in regex so that the message will contain "\n". Please help. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the expected output and share some code to show how  you are doing it. And the regex doesn't seem to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i wrote a little test program and tried it in normal java

```
String test = "Number=12345678; Message=this \n is \n a \n sample \n text;";
System.out.println(test);
String[] out = test.split(";");
int i = 0;
for (String part : out)
{
   System.out.println(i);
   i++;
   System.out.println(part);
}
```

and thats my output

```
Number=12345678; Message=this 
 is 
 a 
 sample 
 text;
0
Number=12345678
1
 Message=this 
 is 
 a 
 sample 
 text
```

So i think this is the correct split in Number and Message part.

Hope this helps